# Difference between constructor and getter and setter

Tags: java

I have been doing assignments for college projects. At one point, I am getting confused at what is actually the use of getter and setter when you can actually use constructor methods to achieve the same results. I have searched and found many answers but not satisfactory explanation.
I have laptop.java as follows

```
public class laptop {
    private String model;

    public laptop(String brand){
     model=brand;
        }

    public String toString(){
        return "Laptop Brand is: "+ model;
    }
}
```

and the laoptopRecords.java that is calling constructor as

```
public class laptopRecords {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        laptop laptop1=new laptop("Dell");
        System.out.println(laptop1);
    }

}
```

Here I am not using the getter and setter methods and I get desired result for every laptop object.

If I do in another way using getter and setter methods in laptopRecord.java as follows, I get the same result. But I am not getting what is use of getter and setter methods if actually we can achive the results with constructor as well.

laptop.java with getter and setter

```
public class laptop {
    private String model;

    public laptop(String brand){
     model=brand;
        }
    public void setlaptop(String brand){
        model=brand;        
    }
    public String getlaptop(){
        return model;       
    }
    public String toString(){
        return "Laptop Brand is: "+ model;
    }
}
```

Comment: Constructor is called only when the object is created. If you want to change something, or get something at any other point, you need separate methods for that.

Comment: Setters are used generally to update/modify/edit the data, while constructor are used to initiate the data

Comment: That `toString` method is a form of getter.

Comment: Constructors are not methods, for one thing.

Comment: You should follow the Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I tell you an easy way:**

***getters() and setters():***

- actually getters() and setters available in POJO/Bean classes.
- The main reason used for getters() setters() in java classes is **To get the Java Encapsulation Mechanism.**
- In POJO/Bean classes we declare all attributes as a **private.** that means these class attributes can't use in other classes and packages, so in this, we can achieve Encapsulation.

***Constructors():***

- I think you know the definition of constructor, **The constructor is used for initializing the attributes giving our own values rather than storing the default values**
- We can say another way i.e **Constructor used for creating an object and setters used for changing the values inside object, getters() user for getting the values, this is only the main difference.**

Answer (score 4):

Getters are always nice. If you forgot what brand you set at creation, it would be nice to have a way of getting it out of that object. What if you got that object from somewhere else? Figuring out the brand using a getter is easy that way. But getters should only be available on directly exposed values. No need to create a getter for `internalVersionString` if it should not be publically known. But having a getter for `colour` would be nice... after all, you can see the colour by looking at the laptop (which is a bad analogy for OOP, but it's fitting here IMHO).

Regarding setters... if you have only one attribute, there is not much of a (visible) difference indeed. But what lies beyond that is a deeper subject... mutability. Of course, using a constructor has a greater overhead than simply setting the attribute (getting memory for a whole new object vs. getting memory for a string).

A nice example of not using setters is the `String` class in Java. A Java `String` is immutable; once created, it cannot be changed whatsoever. If you want to replace characters or remove some parts, what you get is not a changed String, but instead a brand new String with the desired changes made. But what if you had a class called `TextDocument`, that contained a whole file's worth of data? Having no ability to replace parts of that one without creating a whole new `TextDocument` could be hindering.

Having setters automatically means your object is mutable; that means, your object is not fixed upon creation, but can be changed later on. An `ArrayList` would be a nice example here. You'd certainly not want to allocate a whole new list only to change a single value.

The difference between mutable and immutable are not as clear when using simple cases like your `laptop` class. Using immutable classes comes in handy when doing parallel work, using mutable classes comes in handy when handling big objects with a large amount of memory needed to allocate.

There's no one-fits-all solution for that problem. But for exposed attributes which should be directly changeable, a setter would be convenient instead of having to construct a whole new object. Imagine a class with multiple attributes... taking your `laptop` for example, having a brand, a size, a colour and whatnot. If you just want to change the colour, having to construct a new laptop and copying over all the other attributes would be tedious, wouldn't it? A setter would make life easier for you in that case. Just call `yourLaptop.setBrand("Dill");` and continue using that laptop. No reason to spend 500 bucks (or rather... bytes) for another one.

Answer (score 0):

When you extend a class having private data members ,then getters and setters method will help you to access that data members in subclass.While constructor only initialize the data members.

Answer (score 0):

1. Constructor is used to initialize object.
2. When we use parameterized constructor to pass parameter it only call once.
3. Means you can only pass parameter once.
4. if you call it more then 1 time each time a new object created in memory.
5. While getter and setter can be called according to your use many time to set or get values